# How to grep for special character NUL (^@^@^@)

Tags: linux, unix

File:

```
O000000667520994000000074720121112000000N^@^@^@
```

I used the below command but it doesn't work.

```
grep "^@^@^@" *
```

Answer (score 74):

You can grep for any characters including control/non-printable characters in perl-regexp mode (-P) by its hex code:

```
grep -Pa '\x00' ...
```

Comment: I can't find a way to check if file contains only ASCII=0 bytes... `grep -Pv '\x00' file` does not work in Cygwin...

Comment: @mpy Without `-a` (sometimes?) it doesn't even find the pattern. Thanks! Might help @pbies as well.

Comment: but you might not see them, pipe to `| cat -v`

Comment: Mac grep doesn't support `-P` unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 17):

`^@` is not a carat `^` and at-sign `@`, it's one character. It's how some programs display the NUL character—ASCII value 0, also known as `\0` in C.

Here I've created a file with a NUL byte in it.<sup>†</sup> Notice that I use `cat -v` to show non-printing characters.

```
$ cat -v blah
hello
null^@
hi
$ hexdump -C blah
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a 6e 75  6c 6c 00 0a 68 69 0a     |hello.null..hi.|
0000000f
```

Grep has trouble finding NULs since they're used to terminate strings in C. Sed, however, can do the job:

```
$ sed -n '/\x0/p' blah
null
$ sed -n '/\x0/p' blah | cat -v
null^@
```

---

<sup>†</sup> In vi, in insert mode press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd> to insert a null byte.

Comment: † In vi, to find a null character, press `/` to start searching and then `Ctrl-V`, `Ctrl-Shift-@` to insert a null byte, and then `ENTER`.  Then use `N`ext and `P`revious to show found instances.

Answer (score 10):

If `grep -P` doesn't work (e.g. on OS X), try this:

```
grep -E '\x00' ...
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I does not with my version: grep (GNU grep) 2.14

Comment: This answer is for BSD grep, try the top answer for GNU grep: `grep -Pa '\x00' ...`

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can add special characters when prefixed with `C-q` or `C-v`. So you can, for example

```
grep 'Ctrl-vCtrl-a' file.txt
```

The search string should be read as `control key` + `character v`, followed by `control key` + `character a`, which searches for ASCII value SOH (01). Unfortunately this doesn't work for the NUL character.

Answer (score -3):

Character ^@ is the NUL char, so I'm afraid that it cannot be grepped directly.

Your best option would be probably to write a simple program that searches for this sequence of bytes.

Alternatively you may try to convert it into some form of hexadecimal dump (`od`, `xxd` or so) and grep into the output of it. But frankly speaking, it would be tricky to get it right.